# Pivot with a table variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I'm unable to use a pivot the data of a table variable.

Its giving following error on run-time:
"Must declare the scalar variable @reportData"

I have tried as mentioned below

```
DECLARE @reportData TABLE
(
PERSONID NUMERIC(6,0),
personname VARCHAR(100),
bu VARCHAR(50),
timeperiod VARCHAR(100),
wfstatus VARCHAR(100)
)
```

I'm using the below dynamic pivot query

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query=N'SELECT PERSONID,PERSONNAME,BU,wfstatus,'+@datelist+'
from(
SELECT PERSONID,PERSONNAME,BU,wfstatus,timeperiod
FROM
'+@reportData+') AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT
(group by wfstatus 
FOR timeperiod
 IN('+@datelist+')
) as pivorttable
select personid,personname,bu,timeperiod,status from pivorttable'

execute(@query);
```

can some one help me in this?
I need to use only table variable to maintain concurrency issue.!

Comment: Why have you tagged this with three different versions of SQL Server? If 2008+ you can pass a readonly table valued parameter into dynamic SQL. Just use a local `#temp` table instead though. This is session scoped so shouldn't cause any issues with concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM'+@reportData` attempts to add a table variable to a string, which wont work as a table variable is not a string.

Given that you presumably need to populate `reportData` first you could switch to an explicitly created temp table

```
create table #reportData 
(
PERSONID NUMERIC(6,0)
...
)
```

Or use a Table Type;

```
--run once
CREATE TYPE ReportDataType AS TABLE (
    PERSONID NUMERIC(6,0),
    personname VARCHAR(100)
)


declare @reportData ReportDataType
insert @reportData values 
    (111, 'bob'),
    (222, 'alice')

declare @query nvarchar(max) = N'select * from @T'

exec sp_executesql @query, N'@T ReportDataType readonly', @reportData
```